# Validating a 13-character South African ID

Tags: java

I want to validate that the user has entered 13 characters only. This is the code that I have which does not work. Here's an idea of my code:

```
if ((ID.length() < 12) && (ID.length() > 12))  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid 13 character ID");
    myId = ReceiveNumbers.nextLong();
}
```

Comment: The length will never be both less than and greater than 12...

Comment: Logic error side-if something doesn't work you need to be descriptive: when does it fail? For what data? Don't make people guess.

Comment: That should probably just be `!=` such as `if (longIdToStr.length() != 13)`

Comment: `if (longIdToStr.length()  != 13 )` will be the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your current code:

1. `String.length()` starts with 1, so your return should be exactly 13;
2. As others have stated, the string cannot be both greater than and less than 12 (or 13 for that matter);

That being considered, you should attempt the following.

```
if (longIdToStr.length() != 13)  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid 13 character ID");
    myId = ReceiveNumbers.nextLong();
}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain to me a basic repeat-until loop in java. A simple example will be appreciated.

Comment: @Mode - a "repeat-until" would be a "do-while" in Java. See [this tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_do_while_loop.htm).

Answer (score 3):

- **`longIdToStr.length()` can't be both lower than 12 `&&` (AND) greater than 12!**
- If you want your string to have 13 characters, then **you should compare `longIdToStr.length()` against 13, not 12**.

---

You probably meant to use the `||` (OR) operator instead of `&&` (AND):

```
if (longIdToStr.length() < 13 || longIdToStr.length() > 13)
```

(if `longIdToStr.length()` is lower than 12 OR `longIdToStr.length()` is greater than 12)

---

You could simply do this instead:

```
if (longIdToStr.length() != 13)
```

(if `longIdToStr.length()` is not equal to 13)